# DFP small business - video custom criteria

Tags: google-dfp

We're experiencing issues with custom criteria and video. The issue is simple, custom criteria just don't seem to work at all for video tags. Some details:

We've booked a test video on sponsorship 100% with custom criteria domaincode=nl and game-id=21485 in DFP small business.

Our video link http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?sz=640x480&iu=/1053551/Video-Preloader&ciu_szs&impl=s&gdfp_req=1&env=vp&output=xml_vast2&unviewed_position_start=1&url={url}&description_url={descriptionUrl}&correlator={timestamp}&cust_params=domaincode%3Dnl%26pagetype%3Dgame%26ingame-ad%3Dtrue%26categories%3D3%2C65%2C80%2C98%2C406%26game-id%3D21485%26

{url}, { descriptionUrl} and {timestamp} are correctly replaced.

The custom criteria are made according to: https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/1080597

Decoded cust_params:
domaincode=nl&pagetype=game&ingame-ad=true&categories=3,65,80,98,406&game-id=21485&

Our google representative told us to look into our video player implementation, which I did and didn't find anything out of order. It uses the IMA3 SDK just like the video inspector from google, which I normally use for testing.

Video inspector: developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/vastinspector_dual?hl=nl

Does anybody have a system running with video + custom criteria and sees a flaw in our setup? Is this a DFP Premium only feature?

Thanks in advance,
Casper

Answer (score 0):

Good news, the ima3 sdk is doing it's job just fine. For some reason the video inspector now shows the correct video with custom criteria, which means that I can fix it also on our sites. I can't explain why it took DFP more than 2 hours to activate the video, but I'm just glad that it works.

Conclusion, custom criteria for video on DFP small business works just fine. Use https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/1080597 for implementation details.